# why note does not place where I want it to in callouts package

Tags: annotations

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[text=black, background=white, arrow=black]{callouts}
\usetheme{Madrid}


%\title{Vacuum decay and Gravitational waves}
\title{True vacuum first order phase transition}
\subtitle{Transition amplitude calculation for a toy model}
\author{Lourenço Entrudo, Gonçalo Costa }
\institute{CFTC Summer Internships}
\date{28 July 2023}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\section{The starting point}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{annotate}{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{potencial invertido.png}}{0.25}
        %\helpgrid[black]
        \note{1,1}{\tiny $\phi_+$}
    \end{annotate}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}


\section{Vacuum decay and Toy Potential}
\begin{frame}{Vacuum decay and Toy Potential}
    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Im using this code to annotate an image. However, the command `\note{1,1}{\tiny $\phi_+$}` doesn't place the note where I want it to, placing it at the origin instead.

Comment: Unfortunately your code does not compile. Please add the missing lines. Thank you // Also we don't have your image file. Suggestion: rename it, so it no longer contains a blank space.

Comment: @MS-SPO i've edited the post so it displays the full code; I've also added the image file.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile still, what tex version are you using?

Comment: @JamesT I'm using overleaf